# Undefined method `checksum' for Chef::Resource::Directory

Tags: checksum, chef-infra, recipe

While running a recipe for Pyramid, the following is failing in `chef-solo`:

```
================================================================================
Error executing action `create` on resource 'directory[/etc/service/pyramid/supervise/status]'
================================================================================

NoMethodError
-------------
undefined method `checksum' for Chef::Resource::Directory

Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /var/chef-solo/cookbooks/project/recipes/pyramid.rb

 22:     directory "#{node['runit']['service_dir']}/pyramid#{dir}/supervise/#{f}" do
 23:       owner login
 24:       group login
 25:     end
 26:   end

Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /var/chef-solo/cookbooks/project/recipes/pyramid.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in from_file'

directory("/etc/service/pyramid/supervise/status") do
  provider Chef::Provider::Directory
  action :create
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  path "/etc/service/pyramid/supervise/status"
  cookbook_name :project
  recipe_name "pyramid"
  owner "myusername"
  group "myusername"
  mode 420
end
```

Why is this getting "undefined method `checksum`" and what can I do about it?

This error doesn't appear to be consistent. Sometimes the chef run appears to hang. Other times, after multiple runs, chef is able to pass this point.

I'm running on a vanilla Ubuntu server 12.04LTS with chef installed with a deploy script:

```
sudo apt-get install -y ruby1.9.1 ruby1.9.1-dev make &&
sudo gem1.9.1 install chef ohai --no-rdoc --no-ri
```

This is the full Pyramid recipe:

```
login = node["user"]["login"]
home = node["user"]["home"]
app_root = node["user"]["app_root"]

runit_service "pyramid" do #, :template_name => "site" do
  template_name "pyramid"
  owner login
  group login
  options({
    :login => login,
    :app_root => app_root,
    :home => home,
    :config => "#{app_root}/config/gunicorn.conf.py"
  })
end

["", "/log"].each do |dir|
  directory "#{node['runit']['service_dir']}/pyramid#{dir}/supervise" do
    mode "0755"
  end
  %w(ok control status).each do |f|
    directory "#{node['runit']['service_dir']}/pyramid#{dir}/supervise/#{f}" do
      owner login
      group login
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Not really pyramid-the-framework specific, is it?

Comment: There are quite a few chef recipes you could go through and remove the target of the technology if you're in the editing mood - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recipe

Comment: `recipe` sounds like a candidate for burniating; it's very meta.

Comment: Should /etc/service/pyramid/supervise/status be a directory or a file? May be it fails, when there is a file with the same name/path?

Comment: @DracoAter thanks for the tip - used it for a fix which I've posted in the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was my solution - found after some hacking around plus the tip from @Draco-ater...

Where the recipe referenced `directory("/etc/service/pyramid/supervise/status")`, the status 'directory' is a file that already exists which was causing issues.

In addition, the script also tried to update the `control` and `ok` pipes as directories - which was also failing. I solved this by using `bash` and `chmod`:

```
bash "give_perms_pyramid" do
    user "chef"
    cwd "#{node['runit']['service_dir']}/pyramid#{dir}/supervise"
    code <<-EOH
        sudo chown myuser:root control
        sudo chmod g+rw control
    EOH
```

Maybe that will help someone.